# mysql count problem

Tags: sql, mysql

`SQL 1`

```
SELECT (
COUNT(contract.contract_notesid) + (SELECT COUNT(contract_notesid) 
FROM quotation WHERE quotation.contract_notesid = contract.contract_notesid)

) AS total 

FROM contract where contract_notesid = '48'
```

`total 2`

`SQL 2`

```
SELECT (
COUNT(contract.contract_notesid) + (SELECT COUNT(contract_notesid) 
FROM quotation WHERE quotation.contract_notesid = 48)

) AS total 

FROM contract where contract_notesid = '48'
```

`total 6`

`contract table`: 2 records  `quotation table`: 4 records

1.why diffent count?

2.`SQL 2`,Is there any better way to do?(`total: 6`)

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do exactly. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @r-dub get total from 2 tables

Comment: try manually counting contracts with contract_notesid = 48 from your table... compare your manual result to your two sql queries above... which one tallies is the correct query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These queries are not equivalent. You are performing a JOIN (Cartesian product then trimming result set) but in the second one you have duplicate results since you are matching on a different condition, causing your total to be higher. The 'correct' query of these two depends on what you're trying to do..

Possible solution -

you 'could' be trying to do something like the following:

```
select count(contract.contract_notesid) + count(quotation.contract_notesid)
from contract
join quotation
on contract.contract_notesid = quotation.contract_notesid
where contract.contract_notesid = '48'
```

but this is a wild guess until you provide more info.

Comment: @Alex The sql 2(total 6),has other way to query?

Comment: @LNXA It's 3am, I'll check back on this thread tomorrow morning maybe you'll have some more specific requirements :[

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your support. HK is 4:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MySQL expert (I know some Oracle), so I would abstain from guessing and answering your first question.

For your second question:
What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

If you want the number of `records in the quotation table + number of records in the contract table` with `contract_notesid = 48`, then all you need is

```
select   
(
  (select count(contract.contract_notesid) FROM contract where contract_notesid = '48')
  +  
  (SELECT COUNT(contract_notesid) FROM quotation WHERE quotation.contract_notesid = 48)  
) as TOTAL  
from dual
```

If you want the count of all quotations that have a contract associated with it, for `contract_notesid = 48`, then you need a join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total
  FROM quotation quotation, 
       contract contract
WHERE quotation.contract_notesid = contract.contract_notesid
  AND quotation.contract_notesid = '48'
```

Comment: @Nivas sql2 total:8    only 6 in 2 tables

Comment: How many records you have in each table, for `contract_notesid = '48'?`

Comment: `contract table`: 2 records  `quotation table`: 4 records

Comment: If the 2nd sql is returning 8, then it looks like it is doing a cartesian product. (4*2 = 8). Are you sure you copy-pasted the complete sql? The answer for the 2nd SQL should be 2 (only 2 matching records).

Comment: SQL 1: dual is the third table ? No need to use third tables.

Comment: SQL query: SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM quotation quotation, contract contract WHERE quotation.contract_notesid = contract.contract_notesid AND quotation.contract_notesid = '48' ;  `total 8`  (copy from phpmyadmin,I tested 10 times) I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the selection on the `quotation.contract_notesid = 48`, but the selection on contract is `where contract_notesid = '48'` - the latter is quoted, while the former is not. This implies that the quotation and contract fields are of different types, and that the query is doing some implicit conversion.

I suggest explicitly converting the numeric field to a string, in the `WHERE` clause of the first query.